# how to center allign a text in a custom x y coordinate using reportlab

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab

I am trying to develop one python app. the app should print text in an a4 page and on that a4 sheet already there are 4 rectangle boxes, i have to put text in center allign format in each box. the image is attached as reference.[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8AwZ.png)
i have written something like this using reportlab.

```
self.canvas = canvas.Canvas(name, pagesize=landscape(A4))
self.canvas.drawCentredString(x1,y1,"c1")
```

but i am not achieving my goal.

Answer (score 0):

[rlhelper](https://pypi.org/project/rlhelper/) has some useful functions which may be of assistance here. 
If you can identify the mid-point x-coordinate of each box, the following function can work:

import rlhelper
simpleCentredstring('canvas', 'x', 'y', 'string', 'fontcolor', 'font (+weight)','fontsize')